# irb require HTML module from rails 4.0

Tags: css-selectors, ruby-on-rails-4, irb

I'm completely new to both ruby and rails and have a very basic problem testing some code from the irb command line.

I want to take an arbitrary html string and be able to css selectors on it using the rails HTML module: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/Selector.html

I am in the root directory or my rails app and want to simply include this module, create an "element" from the string, then run a selector to see if it matches.

What I want to do is something the following:

```
irb> require 'html'
irb> elem = HTML::Document('<div class="nothing"></div>')
irb> sel = HTML::Selector('div.nothing')
irb> matches = sel.select(elem)
```

However, my naive attempt to require 'html' has failed:

```
irb(main):016:0> require 'html'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- html
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from (irb):16
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is, you want to use it from `irb` where you would want to use the `rails console`.

If you need to use it from `irb` you will have to require the right path:

```
require "action_view"
=> true
require "action_view/vendor/html-scanner"
=> true
HTML::Selector.new "form.login[action=/login]"
=> #<HTML::Selector:0x007f8b5c0fb268 @source="form.login[action='/login']", @tag_name="form", @attributes=[["class", /(^| )login($| )/], ["action", /^\/login$/]], @pseudo=[], @negation=[], @alternates=[], @depends=nil>
```

Comment: `rails console` is what I wanted but both approaches worked. Thanks!